# Need help in PHP with non-blocking sockets for IRC bot

Tags: php, sockets, irc

I've been learning to write an IRC bot in PHP and it's been working great but the blocking has become an issue because I want certain actions to happen based on a timer.  I've been trying to learn about non-blocking but im struggling to get it working correctly.  Can anyone have a look at my code and let me know where im going wrong?

```
<?php

$ircPort = 6667;
$ircBotNick = "CaveBot";
$ircBotPrefix = "!";
$ircBotPass = "";
$ircBotIdent = "CaveBot";
$ircBotRealName = "Cavemans Bot Script";
$ircDefaultChannel = "#CaveDen";
$ircServer = "localhost";

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

$error = socket_connect($socket, $ircServer, $ircPort);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

while (1) {

$read   = array($socket);
$write  = NULL;
$except = NULL;
$num_changed_sockets = socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0);

if ($num_changed_sockets === false) {
    // Error handling
} else if ($num_changed_sockets > 0) {

    $data = socket_read($socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
    echo $n . " - ";
    $d = explode(' ', $data);

    $d = array_pad($d, 10, '');

    if ($d[0] === 'PING') {

        socket_write($socket, "PONG $d[1]");
    }
    print_r($data);
}
```

}

I think i'm not handling the read/incoming data correctly.  It starts to connect but freezes up after a message from the server about looking up hostname.  When I use similar code that has blocking, i get a ping and welcome message after the lookup.

Comment: ignore the $echo $n." - ";   I was using to confirm the loop was active but have removed the rest of the code

Comment: What is the _message from the server about looking up hostname_ that causes the shown code to _freeze_? Besides, the `socket_select` _timeout_ 0 is a bad idea, causing a busy loop.